# My Threading Chat Server isn't work in parallel . Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sockets, server, python-multithreading, sametime

Can someone tell me how to make my code work in parallel , that the client see immediately what other sent and if someone joined the chat . (the code isn't finished because I stopped when I saw the function "receive" and "startconnection" doesn't work in the same time)
the receive function is getting data from the client and sending it to everyone except himself . the startconnection function start connection with clients.
I need that new will client always be able to connect the server and send and get data from other clients.

The Code:

```
import socket
import threading
import time

add=[]
d=[]
i=0

def startconnection():
    time.sleep(0.6)
    server_socket.listen(1)
    (client_socket,client_address)=server_socket.accept()
    print "new client has connected"
    if i!=0:    
        sendall("new client connected",i)
    global d
    global add
    global i
    add=add+[client_address]
    d=d+[client_socket]
    i+=1


x=True
def receive(tmp):
    time.sleep(0.6)
    global x
    global i
    global d
    print "I am here again working with client number: %d ,the numbers of                             
                                       connected clients are : %d" %(tmp,i)
    data=d[tmp].recv(1024)
    if data!= "":
        print "needs to send everyone exept the sender this data: %s" %                 
                                                                     (data)
        sendall(data,findplace(d[tmp]))
    print "Finish working with client"


def sendall(text,nottosend):
    print "got to sendall"
    global i
    global d
    tp=0
    while tp<i:
        if tp!=nottosend:
            d[tp].send(text)
        tp+=1


def run():
    global i
    thread = threading.Thread(target=startconnection())
    thread.daemon = True
    thread.start()

    time.sleep(0.6)
    b=0
    while i != 0 and b<=i-1:
        time.sleep(0.6)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=receive(b)).start()
        b+= 1


def findplace(client_socket):
    global d
    i=0
    while i<len(d):
        if client_socket==d[i]:
            return i
        else:
            i+=1
    print "!!!!!!!!!!!Eror in findplace!!!!!!!!!!!"
    return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_socket = socket.socket()
    server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1', 231))
    while x:
        thread = threading.Thread(target=run())
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
```

Comment: I can point out some obvious problems.  `thread=threading.Thread(target=run())` calls `run()` immediately in the *current* thread.  It should be `thread = threading.Thread(target=run)`.  Same for your other threads.  Also, use meaningful variable names. The name of `x` should indicate why it is used.  Fix those things and come back with an actionable problem.  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: removed new lines

Comment: You might want to look into using ZeroMQ library instead of `socket` module.